# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$auth

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have database table called 'server_admins' and 'users'.

server_admins table has row called 'auth'

users table have 'steam_id' and 'username' rows

'auth' and 'steam_id' have same result like: STEAM_0:0:113434

How can i take from 'auth' to 'steam_id' and get username?

Im trying like that:

```
            $serveradmins = DB::table('server_admins')->get();
        $serveradmins->auth = DB::table('server_admins')->auth->get();
        $serveradmins->username = User::where('steam_id', '=', $serveradmins->auth)->first()->username;
        $this->pageView('servers::admins', ['serveradmins' => $serveradmins]);
```

But getting error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$auth
```

Sorry if really dumb ask, i just learning laravel :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using multiple queries to get what you already have, but keep in mind that `->get()` returns a `Collection`, not a single record. Change your code to:

```
$serverAdmin = DB::table('server_admins')->first();
```

This line:

```
$serveradmins->auth = DB::table('server_admins')->auth->get();
```

Makes no sense; If you use the above, `$serverAdmin->auth` is already available, so calling another query to get it is redundant. The rest is alright:

```
$serveradmin->username = User::where('steam_id', '=', $serveradmins->auth)->first()->username;
$this->pageView('servers::admins', ['serveradmins' => $serveradmins]);
```

If `$serverAdmins` is supposed to be an array (or `Collection`), you'll need to do some looping:

```
$serveradmins = DB::table('server_admins')->get();
foreach($serverAdmins AS $serverAdmin){
    $serveradmin->username = User::where('steam_id', '=', $serveradmin->auth)->first()->username;
}
$this->pageView('servers::admins', ['serveradmins' => $serveradmins]);
```

Comment: Thank u verry much! Working like a charm and now i understand that fail i did. Thanks again!